# How to get column names in SQLAlchemy result?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is additional question to my previous one here - [How to access column values in SQLAlchemy result list after a join a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006924/how-to-access-column-values-in-sqlalchemy-result-list-after-a-join-a-query).

I have this join query.

```
result = db.query(Order, Item).join(Item, Item.order_id == Order.internal_id, isouter=True).filter(Item.order_id == order_id).all()
```

How do I get all the column names of the result?

Answer (score 0):

Query has a `column_descriptions` attribute. So you can do `result.column_descriptions`

Checkout this [Query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=column_description#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.column_descriptions) page for more detail and example.